# Sieve filter rule

Tags: postfix-mta, sieve

I want using SIEVE to filter e-mails in a postfix/dovecot installation.

Assuming there are multiple recipients in the TO field of an email.

Is there a SIEVE rule to match an email if the TO field contains an email address with a specific domain name **and at the same time** contains an email address with a domain name different to that specific domain name?

For example, let the specific domain be "example.com".

- `TO: a@example.com, b@abc.com` -> MATCH
- `TO: a@xyz.com, b@abc.com` -> NO MATCH (since no address with example.com)
- `TO: a@example.com` -> NO MATCH (since no address different to example.com)
- `TO: a@example.com, b@example.com` -> NO MATCH (since no address different to example.com)
- `TO: a@abc.com` -> NO MATCH

Answer (score 1):

What turned out to working for me is the following:

```
require "regex";
if allof ( address :domain :is "To" "example.com",
           header :regex "to" "@[^(example.com)]+"
         ) { ... } else { ... }
```

Thus, you can match "some domain different to example.com" with the statement `header :regex "to" "@[^(example.com)]+"`

**SIDENOTE**

Some thoughts about Kaspar's suggestion (which did not work for me).

It turned out that

```
if address :domain :is "To" "example.com" {
```

matches if **any** of the emails in the To-field contains example.com. The `not`-statement just negates this result. I.e.

```
 if not address :domain :is "To" "example.com" {
```

matches if **none** of the emails in the To-field contains example.com.

As a consequence, combining both statements within `allof` does **never** match.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your code.  Does sieve regex extension support negative look-ahead?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: The following rule does not work, see the other answer for the reason.]

I'm not an expert on the Sieve mail filtering language, but have you tried something like the following, using [`address`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228#section-5.1), [`not`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228#section-5.8), and [`allof`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228#section-5.2)?

```
if allof (address :domain :is "To" "example.com", not address :domain :is "To" "example.com") {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relational` extension to ensure the existence of an email address with a domain name different to the specific one.  See [Extended Example section of RFC5231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5231.html#section-7).

```
require "relational";

if allof (
    address :domain :is "To" "example.com",
    address :value "ne" :domain "To" "example.com"
) {
    # match
} else {
    # no match
}
```